# onPerformSync called on emulator but not physical device

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract, android-syncadapter

I've built an Account sync adapter to show contacts from the app in local contact book.

There is a fake authonticator that provides account. Also account is syncable

```
    ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, 1);
    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, true);
```

This account is displayed in all accounts on the device:

[image]

I've tried to trigger onPerformSync by system - from settings in menu press 'sync now' and programatically:

```
public static void triggerRefresh() {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
    b.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
    Account account = AccountAuthenticatorService.GetAccount();

    if (ContentResolver.isSyncPending(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY)  ||
            ContentResolver.isSyncActive(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY)) {
        ContentResolver.cancelSync(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY);
    }

    ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, 1);
    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, true);
    ContentResolver.requestSync(
            account, // Sync account
            ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,authority
            b);
}
```

It works fine on emulator, but on several devices (sony, samsung) it not triggered at all (I've tried to log smth in onPerformSync method but never see this log).

I've tried to find such problem, but nothing helps, I can't make onPerformSync force to be called.

What the main difference between emulator and device according to syncAdapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the reason of this issue:

`onPerformSync` method will never be called until you don't have internet connection. On several devices and emulators there was an internet connection but on others you can't trigger this method.